# Select a row after GroupBy based on a conditional

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by, row

I have a first dataframe:

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'subject':[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3], 
                        'trial' :[2,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,15],
                        'diff_rows':['nan',10,1,1,1,1,1,1,'nan',1,1,4,1,1,1,3]})

print(df1)

    subject  trial diff_rows
0         2      2       nan
1         2     12        10
2         2     13         1
3         2     14         1
4         2     15         1
5         2     16         1
6         2     17         1
7         2     18         1
8         3      3       nan
9         3      4         1
10        3      5         1
11        3      9         4
12        3     10         1
13        3     11         1
14        3     12         1
15        3     15         3
```

1. I would like to GroupBy subject
2. Then select row 1 if in row 1 diff_rows > 1
3. Else, select row 2
4. To store in a dictionary or dataframe subject and trial of the row selected

I have been trying a couple of options but it seems that it didn't work because Series has no .nth object

```
s = df1.groupby(['subject']).apply(lambda frame: frame.nth(1) if frame.diff_rows.nth(1).gt(1) else frame.nth(2)) 
s = df1.loc[df1.groupby(['subject']).apply(lambda frame: frame.nth(1) if frame.diff_rows.nth(1).gt(1) else frame.nth(2)), ('subject', 'trial')].to_dict(orient='record')
```

My expected output is:

```
    subject  trial diff_rows
0         2     12        10
1         3     5         1
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry! I have added the output to the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your logic, we can do exploit the fact that `diff_rows` is `NaN` on the first row of the group:

```
s1 = df1.diff_rows.eq(1).where(df1.diff_rows.isna().shift())
df1.loc[s1.eq(0) | s1.shift().eq(1)]
```

output:

```
    subject  trial  diff_rows
1         2     12       10.0
10        3      5        1.0
```